# Only selecting first with any simple selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I want to select every row in a table, but everything i try, it only selects the first. 
I tried the following snippet, which I found somewhere. It doesn't help me out though.

```
function addJQuery(callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");

    script.setAttribute("src", 
            "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");

    script.addEventListener('load', 
                function() {
                    var script = document.createElement("script");
                    script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
                    document.body.appendChild(script);
                }, 
                false);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

This is the code it's all about:

```
var rows = $("#report_list tr");
```

Comment: I would use a class as selector.

Comment: Where is that code used, are there any errors in the console? That first chunk of code simply creates a `script` element and appends it to include jQuery

Comment: @x_maras: Because it's greasemonkey aka a Userscript I am not able to change the HTML in a way it helps.

Comment: @tymeJV: There where no errors. This function above is a snippet which is called and the script i add is the callback.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you're including the jquery document.ready function when using a jquery selector.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rows = $("#report_list tr");
    console.log(rows);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces in the src: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");

When I removed the spaces it worked: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tbsXR/)

```
script.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
```

Comment: In the source code I use there is indeed no space. But for some reason, after pasting it here, ( first time here, the space appeared. I am trying to remove it here too.